# format dictionary for with new lines and tabs when converting to string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, code-readability

Is there a simple way to format a string of a dictionary?

I have a dictionary that I want to save into a file, to do this I am passing it to the file as a string using str(dictionary).

This means that the dictionary looks like this in the file, just one long line:

```
meals = {'chilli': {'ingredients': {'vegetarian mince': 500, 'tin of tomatoes': 1, 'red onion': 1}, 'prep_time': 1, 'storage_time': 3, ...
```

However, I would like it to be formatted like this, for readability, with new lines and tabs to reflect the hierarchy:

```
meals = {
    'chilli': {
        'ingredients': {'vegetarian mince': 500, 'tin of tomatoes': 1, 'red onion': 1},
        'prep_time': 1,
        'storage_time': 3,
        ...
```

Is there a simple/best practice way to achieve this?

I have been able to achieve some of this but not all of it with `.replace()` and could probably manage it all through a lot of iterating through the dictionary but was wondering if there was a better way, `.replace()` and iterating through the dictionary both feel clunky and/or are difficult to achieve exactly what I want.

Comment: There is no easy way to get exactly what you want, because it's isn't consistent -- you have `'chili'` and its value dict on separate lines, but then you have `'ingredients'` and its value dict on the _same_ line.

Comment: Using `json.dump()` with the optional `indent` argument will get you mostly what you want, with a minimum of extra coding.

Comment: Do you really want to include the `meals =` part of this?

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you, I don’t need it exactly had my example, just so I can read it so .dump() will work

Comment: @Chris I do need this as I then import the file and access the dictionary as a variable, however it’s easy to add after formatting.

Comment: ...so you're trying to dynamically generate a Python file? This definitely sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Store data as pure data. That can be in a JSON file, a database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about pprint.

```
import pprint
meals = {...}
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(meals)
```

Comment: Might want to add `sort_dicts=False` so that the ingredients dict doesn't change order.